# Is there a transaction start timestamp - NOW() for txn start - not statement start

Tags: transactions, mariadb, sql-function

I'm investigating temporal queries and I've found what I believe to be an issue with MariaDB (I followed the steps [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/#transaction-precise-history-in-innodb)) - although their implementation of temporal queries seems to be one of the better ones. The MariaDB code is on this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=c52b874c0af0daf052077da7f7c91c0f) (PostgreSQL comparing [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a37b9d190dc330679482cfb11a1bb20c)).

However, in my studies, I have found that MariaDB is lacking a `transaction_timestamp()` function, like they have in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

> PostgreSQL also provides functions that return the start time of the
> current statement, as well as the actual current time at the instant
> the function is called. The complete list of non-SQL-standard time
> functions is:
>
> ```
> transaction_timestamp()
> statement_timestamp()
> clock_timestamp()
> timeofday()
> now()
> ```

I did the following (steps [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/#transaction-precise-history-in-innodb)):

```
create table t 
(
   x int, test timestamp(6),
   start_tid bigint unsigned generated always as row start invisible,
   end_tid   bigint unsigned generated always as row end   invisible,
   period for system_time(start_tid, end_tid)
) with system versioning;
```

Then ran:

```
start transaction;
insert into t (x, test) values (1, now()), (2, now()), (3, now());
select sleep (5);  -- inagine this is some (very) long-running report query
insert into t (x, test) values (11, now()), (12, now()), (13, now());
commit work;
```

and then:

```
select  
  x, test, start_tid, end_tid
from t;
```

got

```
x   test                start_tid   end_tid
1   2021-11-07 11:43:25 60612       18446744073709551615
2   2021-11-07 11:43:25 60612       18446744073709551615
3   2021-11-07 11:43:25 60612       18446744073709551615

-- notice 5 second gap here!    

11  2021-11-07 11:43:30 60612       18446744073709551615
12  2021-11-07 11:43:30 60612       18446744073709551615
13  2021-11-07 11:43:30 60612       18446744073709551615
```

So, I have the timestamps at which the two different sets of inserts happened, but what I **can't** get, is a single transaction start time for the entire transaction in MariaDB.

Doing almost the same thing in PostgreSQL ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a37b9d190dc330679482cfb11a1bb20c)) give me the result

```
x       tx_time                         clock_time
1   2021-11-07 12:01:05.574651  2021-11-07 12:01:05.575062
2   2021-11-07 12:01:05.574651  2021-11-07 12:01:05.575145
3   2021-11-07 12:01:05.574651  2021-11-07 12:01:05.57515

-- here, the tx_time remains unchanged whereas the clock_time changes by 5 seconds as wanted

11  2021-11-07 12:01:05.574651  2021-11-07 12:01:10.577289
12  2021-11-07 12:01:05.574651  2021-11-07 12:01:10.577307
13  2021-11-07 12:01:05.574651  2021-11-07 12:01:10.577324
```

Maybe I could join back to the [mysql.transaction_registry](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqltransaction_registry-table/) table but would prefer to be able to do this within the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
MariaDB [halley]> TRUNCATE TABLE t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.526 sec)

MariaDB [halley]> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [halley]> SELECT @T:=now();
+---------------------+
| @T:=now()           |
+---------------------+
| 2021-11-07 16:21:15 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [halley]> insert into t (x, test) values (1, @T), (2, @T), (3, @T);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.000 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [halley]> select sleep (5);  -- inagine this is some (very) long-running report query
+-----------+
| sleep (5) |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (5.000 sec)

MariaDB [halley]> insert into t (x, test) values (11, @T), (12, @T), (13, @T);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.000 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [halley]> commit work;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.037 sec)

MariaDB [halley]> select  
    ->   x, test, start_tid, end_tid
    -> from t;
+------+----------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
| x    | test                       | start_tid | end_tid              |
+------+----------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
|    1 | 2021-11-07 16:21:15.000000 |       755 | 18446744073709551615 |
|    2 | 2021-11-07 16:21:15.000000 |       755 | 18446744073709551615 |
|    3 | 2021-11-07 16:21:15.000000 |       755 | 18446744073709551615 |
|   11 | 2021-11-07 16:21:15.000000 |       755 | 18446744073709551615 |
|   12 | 2021-11-07 16:21:15.000000 |       755 | 18446744073709551615 |
|   13 | 2021-11-07 16:21:15.000000 |       755 | 18446744073709551615 |
+------+----------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```